# I forgot my Macbook's admin name and password and my user account is changed to standard, how can I change it?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I tried everything using terminal still can't get anything I can't change it using user setting as it demands the password and admin name I used keychain but still didn't get it

Answer (score 1):

Boot up your Mac and hold `CMD + R`
which will boot into Recovery Mode.

Go to `Utilities` and open `Terminal`. Type in the following:

`resetpassword`

Close out the Terminal window and behind it you will find the `Reset Password utility`. All you have to do now is select the user account you want to reset, enter a new password or leave it blank and click Save. Then just simply restart the computer from the Apple menu and login with your new password.

Comment: After changing pass I still can't get admin access maybe the admin name is wrong how can I check that?

Comment: When you go through the process of 'resetpassword' it tells you the name in the drop down menu.

Comment: If this resolved your question, please choose the tick.